# MongoDB Aggregate - Match documents that exist on collection A but not on collection B

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do I match documents that exist on collection A but not on collection B, using mongoDB aggregation?

Collection A:

```
[{
    "_id": 1,
    "operation":"SEC",
    "name":"x"
},{
    "_id": 2,
    "operation": "SEC",
    "name": "y"
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "operation": "SEC",
    "name": "z"
}]
```

Collection B:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "operation": "SEC",
        "name": "x"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "operation": "SEC",
        "name": "y"
    }
]
```

expected output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 3,
        "operation": "SEC",
        "name": "z"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is using a `$lookup` pipeline with the `$$ROOT` and `$match` unmatched documents:

```
db.CollectionA.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "CollectionB",
      let: {root: "$$ROOT"},
      pipeline: [{$match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$$ROOT", "$$root"]}}}],
      as: "collectionB"
  }},
  {$match: {"collectionB.0": {$exists: false}}},
  {$unset: "collectionB"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4i2a3XS2t-f)

Comment: collection A [{ "_id": 1, "operation":"SEC", "name":"x" },{ "_id": 2, "operation": "SEC", "name": "y" }, { "_id": 3, "operation": "SEC", "name": "z" }]

Collection B [{ "user": 1, "operation":"SEC", "name":"x", "date": "2022-10-25" },{ "user": 2, "operation":"SEC", "name":"x", "date": "2022-10-25" } ]

expected output [ { "_id": 3, "operation": "SEC", "name": "z" } ]

I have two collections and I want to match from the first collection to the second collection by date and first collection id and a second user and want to get only those that are not in the second collection.